# Links are changing font on click

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm just finishing off a website and have noticed the links are suddenly flashing to a different font and changing size very quickly when clicked.

The site is up at http://www.belle-jeunesse.com, the issue is most notably in the main navigation bar.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how it can be fixed to, at least, stay the same font?

Comment: Thanks all, after reading the comments I've learnt something about styling anchors, and other elements for that matter, inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On style.css, line 119, remove `a:active`

Answer (score 3):

In your stylesheet, you have this:

```
#g_links a:link, a:visited, a:active {
font-family: Domine; font-size: 1em; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; color: #000; border-bottom: 1px solid; }
```

What I believe you want is this:

```
#g_links a:link, #g_links a:visited, #g_links a:active {
font-family: Domine; font-size: 1em; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; color: #000; border-bottom: 1px solid; }
```

Without the #g_links, you are applying that to all a:visited and a:active links.

Answer (score 2):

In your file : style.css at the line 119.
You have the following rule :

```
#g_links a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    font-family: Domine;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

Just remove the line : a:active OR add #g_links before a:visited and a:active as following :

```
#g_links a:link, #g_links a:visited, #g_links a:active {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed a:active instead as i want this font on the sidebar links.

Comment: Ok ok. If you want this style to apply just to #g_links update the following : " #g_links a:link, a:visited " with this one : " #g_links a:link, #g_links a:visited " So the a:visited is applied only to #g_links

Answer (score 1):

In style.css at row 119, you have this css:

```
#g_links a:link, a:visited, a:active
{
    font-family: Domine;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

The id #g_links only goes for the a:link part. Therefore all links on the page are affected by these style rules when a link is pressed. You might want to add it before a:visited and a:active as well.